# Взаимодействие по usb с vkp80

Tags: python, usb, принтер

Добрый день. Имеется термопринтер vkp 80 и библиотека pyusb

```
printer = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x0dd4, idProduct=0x015d) #нахожу девайс
printer.write(0x2, "$1B $69 $1D $65 $03 $0C") # пытаюсь отправить команду, `описанную в доках`
```

Принтер вздрагивает, а потом раз на 50й распечатывает строки команд в виде текста.Если кто имел дело с подобными вещами прошу помочь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Авторы документации использовали пробелы и знаки `$` для удобства читателей. В самой комманде их быть не должно, только сами бинарные данные.

```
printer.write(0x2, "\x1B\x69\x1D\x65\x03\x0C")
```

Comment: Лучше явно байт-константу использовать: `b"\x1bi..."` (неизвестно какая версия Питона 2 или 3 используется).